# Need help in understanding why ifeq does not work

Tags: makefile

I have the following code in a makefile:

```
TEMP="VBU538ForBootloader"


# build
build: .build-post

.build-pre:
# Add your pre 'build' code here...

.build-post: .build-impl

    @echo "Current config:" $(CONF)
    @echo "Compare to:" $(TEMP)

ifeq ($(CONF),$(TEMP))
    @echo "Making production files for VBU538 .... "
else
    @echo "Skipping production files."
endif
```

Somehow the ifeq does not do what I expected, although it looks to me that my code is similar to other examples. The code produces the following output:

```
Current config: VBU538ForBootloader
Compare to: VBU538ForBootloader
Skipping production files.
```

I am always getting `Skipping production files.` although I expected that the output should have been `Making production files for VBU538 ....`

Does anyone know the reason why its not behaving as expected?

Comment: I am even surprised that you get anything but errors. With what you show you should get an error like: `*** recipe commences before first target.  Stop.` because you have recipes without targets. Are you 100% sure that your Makefile is what you show?

Comment: Sorry I tried to simplify my example, but I have added the lines I think you are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the problem. Thanks for everybody's effort. Eventually I got a hunch that when I was calling make, the wrong make utility was being used. It turned out that I have to use the same make utility as the one that came with the IDE for the microcontroller. I am not sure why that would be needed, but using the make utility that came with the IDE solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so it is difficult to help. It could be that your `COMP` and `TEMP` variables look identical but they are not (spaces, other invisible characters...) You could try to check this by using:

```
    @echo 'Current config: X$(CONF)X'
    @echo 'Compare to: X$(TEMP)X'
```

instead of

```
    @echo "Current config:" $(CONF)
    @echo "Compare to:" $(TEMP)
```

Comment: The result from the above is ```Current config: XVBU538ForBootloaderX```. The complete makefile is generated by the MPLAB-X IDE (based on Netbeans), so unfortunately that is a bit too big to give here. I will try to see if I can make a small reproducible makefile.

Comment: And what about the other variable? Does it also print `Compare to: XVBU538ForBootloaderX` or `Compare to: X VBU538ForBootloaderX` or anything else?